# Sonos Itemtype and item content for list of podcasts and episodes

Tags: sonos

We have several podcasts, each with multiple episodes. Which itemtype should we return for the podcasts and episodes and which type should the item be?

We currently use itemtype.collection for the list of podcasts and episodes and each episode has itemtype.stream and the item is then set to streamMetadata.

This does however not allow for scrubbing.

Podcast:

```
var mediaData = new mediaCollection()
{
    id = string.Format({0}:{1}:{2}",Prefix, moodId, moodItem.Id),
    title = moodItem.Id,
    itemType = itemType.collection,
    onDemand = true,
    liveNow = false,
    language = "Norwegian",
    liveNowSpecified = false,
    albumArtURI = new albumArtUrl() {  Value = moodItem.ImageUri.ToString(), requiresAuthentication = false, requiresAuthenticationSpecified = false}
};
```

Episode:

```
return new mediaMetadata
{
    id = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", Prefix, moodId, podcast.Id, episode.Publishdate.Ticks.ToString()),
    title = episode.Title,
    itemType = itemType.stream,
    mimeType = "audio/mpeg",
    onDemand = true,
    onDemandSpecified = true,
    language = "Norwegian",
    Item = new streamMetadata()
    {
        currentShow = episode.Title,
        logo = new albumArtUrl { Value = podcast.ImageUri.ToString(), requiresAuthentication = false, requiresAuthenticationSpecified = true },
        currentHost = "Someone",
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getMetadataResponse` for podcasts should be of `itemType track` and should include `canResume true`. Check out [this page](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/488) for specific information and examples.

Comment: Works but it still feels wrong to force podcast into an audiobook structure. Audio books and podcasts are two different things and I believe the data/code should reflect this.